# How can I override default.master?

Tags: master-page

I am wanting to update the default.master masterpage in order to hide the search box functionality. This requires just adding some CSS.

What I have done is created a feature and to the feature I have added the new masterpage file. I can activate the feature fine but when I select the new masterpage from site collection settings I get a "File not found" error. I am guessing some of the references in the file are broken. I must have it in the wrong location.

Can someone please have a look and see what I am doing wrong here? I am using MOSS 2007, Visual Studio 2008 with WSPBuilder.

Thanks

EDIT: SORRY I CAN'T GET CODE COPIED PROPERLY

-------- Feature.xml --------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><Feature Id="9014276c-3512-4318-9992-23326ed00540" 
     Title="No Search Master Page"
     Scope="Site"
     Version="1.0.0.0"
     Hidden="FALSE" 
     DefaultResourceFile="core"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" 
     Description="This Feature contains a custom master page which hides the search boxes">
```

---

-------- Elements.xml -------

---

Answer (score 1):

You have two good options:

1. You can indeed apply a custom master page without the search box. This [article](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/03/26/deploying-a-custom-master-page-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) shows how to deploy and apply a custom master page.
2. You can also register a custom control with no HTML output for the delegate control hosting the small search box. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx) describes how to register a custom search box control.

You will need to provide more information about how you upload and reference the master page. Otherwise, it is hard to say what causes the "File not found error". But have a look at the first link above to see how to install and apply a custom master page.